# Crear backup para ambiente python y node

Tags: python, nodejs, npm, pip

Me dispongo a formatear mi laptop pero tengo muchos paquetes de python instalados y acomodados en distintos entornos virtuales, lo mismo me pasa con node.js y muchos modulos que tengo. ¿Existe alguna manera de hacer un backup para todas mis librerias y restaurarlas una vez formatee? asi no tendria que volverlas a instalar manualmente.

Answer (score 2):

En Python puedes usar `pip freeze` para crear un fichero `requirements.txt` de todos tus *virtualenvs* (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt # en el venv de turno
```

En la nueva máquina puedes hacer:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt # en el nuevo venv de turno
```

En nodejs puedes crear un *package.json* y luego hacer:

```
npm install # en el mismo lugar donde esté el package.json
```

Echa un ojo [aquí](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json).

Comment: Y que pasa con los modulos que tengo instalado globalmente, como gulp, grunt, electron, etc? A fin y al cabo esos son los modulos que me preocupan pq son los q estan en la particion del SO que voy a formatear.

Comment: Puedes hacer `npm list -g --depth=0` e incluir lo que te liste en el package.json. Si quieres los paquetes del usuario elimina la opción `-g`. Sinceramente, no sé si nodejs tiene algo como `pip freeze`.